# What does "package foo in Cargo.lock is yanked in registry" mean?

Tags: rust

I was trying to install `ripgrep_all` using `cargo install ripgrep_all`. It gave the following error:

```
% cargo install ripgrep_all
    Updating crates.io index
  Installing ripgrep_all v0.9.6
error: failed to compile `ripgrep_all v0.9.6`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-install5HlOMt`

Caused by:
  failed to select a version for the requirement `cachedir = "^0.1.1"`
  candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.3.0, 0.2.0
  location searched: crates.io index
  required by package `ripgrep_all v0.9.6`
```

Then I searched a bit and [found](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25278277):

> It looks like cachedir yanked version 0.1.1.

And the solution was to:

```
cargo install --locked ripgrep_all
```

I was able to install it successfully. However, During the installation it said:

```
% cargo install --force --locked ripgrep_all
    Updating crates.io index
  Installing ripgrep_all v0.9.6
warning: package `cachedir v0.1.1` in Cargo.lock is yanked in registry `crates.io`, consider running without --locked
warning: package `smallvec v1.4.0` in Cargo.lock is yanked in registry `crates.io`, consider running without --locked
```

It made me curious. What does **Yank** mean in rust world?

Comment: It is the opposite of publishing but it doesn't remove the crate from repository, I guess this could be the most superficial explanation. Publishers yank the specific version of their crates because of some serious issues, if you intend to use one of them, you should carefully investigate the reason of why the crate has been yanked, IMHO I would prefer not to use unless i need a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the package has been marked as ["yanked"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/publishing.html#cargo-yank). This is usually done when the authors of have package have a very compelling reason that a certain version of a package should not be used at all, and to very strongly suggest that the package should not be used. You can ignore yanks with `--force` to force yanked packages to be used, but that is usually a bad idea: packages were usually yanked for a good reason.

In your case: The yanked `cachedir` 0.1.X version is a completely different package with a different author than the newer versions. The older versions are unmaintained and cannot be updated (since `cachedir` now has a different owner who publishes a different package), so the new owner of `cachedir` yanked the older versions. `smallvec` 1.4.0 has a bug where it causes Undefined Behaviour when used with zero-sized types, and that UB is bad enough that it is exceedingly unlikely that you actually want to use that version. The fix to this is to update to a later version of `smallvec` that doesn't have that bug.

Comment: I found https://github.com/rust-lang/crates-io-cargo-teams/issues/9 very useful. However, I found that `--locked` also works instead of `--force`. But not sure what these two arguments actually do.